# Maximal ideal in ring of power series

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If $R$ is a commutative ring with identity we know that the maximal ideals of the ring of power series over $R$ have the form $M’=(M,x)$ where $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. Do you have a counterexample that shows that if $R$ doesn’t have an identity then the theorem doesn’t hold?
I really don’t have any idea where or how to start. 
Reference: Burton’s “First course in ring and ideals” page 117 theorem 7-4

Comment: You mean you want a ring $R$ without identity such that $R[[x]]$ has a maximal ideal that's not of that form? In rings without identity, authors usually require more of an ideal to consider it "maximal". For instance, they sometimes require it to be "modular."  Is there any such requirement or is it just "a proper ideal maximal among proper ideals."

Comment: I am just now considering what $R[x]$ and $R[[x]]$ look like when $R^2=\{0\}$... it seems... interesting, if you define it so that $x\in R[x]$

Comment: Is this an actual question that was posed or is it something less formal?  it's pretty uncommon for algebraists to be interested in such a situation.

Comment: I’m only searching a counterexample to this theorem. I thought that searching among ring without identity was easier than searching among noncommutative ring. However I don’t know what it means to be modular.

Comment: In few words I’m only searching a maximal ideal in the ring of power series over R that doesn’t have that form if R doesn’t have identity or it is noncommutative.

Comment: Well, you might be getting into the weeds asking questions like this one.  Is maximal ideal just "ideal maximal among proper ideals"?  If you want to ask about noncommutative rings, do you want to say "maximal right ideal (maximal among proper right ideals)?"

Comment: And also, does $R[x]$ just mean "linear combinations of powers of $x$ and coefficients from $R$?" another complication of rings without identity, since $x\notin R[x]$ by that definition.

Comment: Yes, for me a maximal ideal is just a maximal ideal among proper ideali.
If R isn’t commutative, the maximal ideal is right.
For the last question, I mean what you say.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure if this suits your needs or not, but if $R=2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and $M=(2x)\lhd R[[x]]$, then $R[[x]]/M\cong R$ has two elements, so $M$ is maximal (in the sense you specified in the comments.)

Comment: I don’t think it is the couterexample I’m searching.
Sorry.  I think that I’m not able to explain what I want to say in English.

Comment: @MathIsLove What condition did I not satisfy?  (I don't mean it rhetorically, I'm asking seriously so I can check if I can improve it.)

Comment: I have to search a maximal ideal M’ in the ring of power series over R (R without identity) that doesn’t have the form M’=(M,x) where M is maximal in R.
You didn’t showed that it can’t have that form but only that it is maximal.

Comment: @MathIsLove It can't have that form because $x\notin R[[x]]$, in my case. And $(2x)\cap R=\{0\}$, so $M$ couldn't be anything but $\{0\}$.

Comment: Oh. It seems to work.
Thanks!